# IT Hit WebDAV AJAX Library - How to open multiple files in MS Word?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

We're trying to use IT Hit WebDAV AJAX Library (ITHitWebDAVClient.js) and see if it can open multiple files from a single call or even multiple calls of the library.

For example, MS Word supports opening of multiple files from WebDab by using File/Open with following parameter:

Example:

```
"http://192.168.1.110/webdav/doc1.docx" "http://192.168.1.110/webdav/doc2.docx"
```

Screenshot:
[image]

We’re trying to do the same thing using ITHitWebDAVClient.js, by doing something like this:

```
ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument("\"http://192.168.1.110/webdav/doc1.docx\" \"http://192.168.1.110/webdav/doc2.docx\"", "/", protocolInstallCallback);
```

,but no matter how we go about it, it doesn’t seem to work.

Opening files sequentially, like this, also doesn’t work:

```
function edit() {
ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument("http://192.168.1.110/webdav/doc1.docx ", "/", protocolInstallCallback);
            ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument("http://192.168.1.110/webdav/doc2.docx ", "/", protocolInstallCallback);
        }
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.DavProtocolEditDocument

sDocumentUrls string  **Coma separated list of document URLs to be opened for editing from server**. *All documents must be located under the same mount URL (specified in sMountUrl parameter)*. Must be a full URL(s) including the domain name.

**The functionality is supported in v3 Beta and later only.